Store errors/exceptions in Custom Object
I have a requirement where I have to catch all the exception(caught/ un-caught). I used try-catch block, but it does not work for all the exception.
For example: It does not work for "CPU time limit exceeded" and may others like that.
Another example would be, I have a 2gp package and I want to run a post installation script, but if it fails, I don't have any logs of that. How to get those?
How could I catch those errors and put into a custom object record?

The alternative, as of the Winter '25 Release, should be to utilise the new free tier Event Monitoring for tracking these kinds of Apex exceptions.
You will be able to access the EventLog file which contains these captured events, which include Limit exceptions such as CPU limits, custom exceptions as well as other built in exceptions.
This has been detailed in the Release Notes here: Track Apex Unexpected Exceptions with Free-Tier Event Monitoring

Simply put, this is not possible.
Exceptions that occur due to hitting a governor limit are uncatchable (relevant documentation, scroll to near the bottom of the page). Your code will immediately halt and the transaction will be rolled back.
